# Type 'org/springframework/http/MediaType' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'org/springframework/util/MimeType'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have upgraded spring from 3.2.1 to 4.0.3

and got:

```
"Type 'org/springframework/http/MediaType' (current frame, stack[1]) is 
 not assignable to 'org/springframework/util/MimeType'"
```

**the full stack trace:**

```
Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping#0': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/condition/ProducesRequestCondition.compareMatchingMediaTypes(Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/condition/ProducesRequestCondition;ILorg/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/condition/ProducesRequestCondition;I)I @83: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'org/springframework/http/MediaType' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'org/springframework/util/MimeType'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @83
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/condition/ProducesRequestCondition', 'org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/condition/ProducesRequestCondition', integer, 'org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/condition/ProducesRequestCondition', integer, integer, 'org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/condition/ProducesRequestCondition$ProduceMediaTypeExpression', 'org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/condition/ProducesRequestCondition$ProduceMediaTypeExpression' }
    stack: { 'org/springframework/http/MediaType', 'org/springframework/http/MediaType' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 0336 051c 1504 9f00 0c15 041c 6436 05a7
    0000010: 0049 1c02 9f00 442b b700 3b1c b900 3d02
    0000020: 00c0 0006 3a06 2db7 003b 1504 b900 3d02
    0000030: 00c0 0006 3a07 1906 1907 b600 4136 0515
    0000040: 0599 0008 1505 a700 1019 06b6 0026 1907
    0000050: b600 26b6 0042 3605 1505 ac            
  Stackmap Table:
    append_frame(@18,Integer)
    append_frame(@73,Object[#178],Object[#178])
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@86,Integer)
    chop_frame(@88,2)

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:760)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:482)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:389)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:294)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4973)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5467)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad type on operand stack
Exception Details:
  Location:
    org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/condition/ProducesRequestCondition.compareMatchingMediaTypes(Lorg/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/condition/ProducesRequestCondition;ILorg/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/condition/ProducesRequestCondition;I)I @83: invokevirtual
  Reason:
    Type 'org/springframework/http/MediaType' (current frame, stack[1]) is not assignable to 'org/springframework/util/MimeType'
  Current Frame:
    bci: @83
    flags: { }
    locals: { 'org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/condition/ProducesRequestCondition', 'org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/condition/ProducesRequestCondition', integer, 'org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/condition/ProducesRequestCondition', integer, integer, 'org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/condition/ProducesRequestCondition$ProduceMediaTypeExpression', 'org/springframework/web/servlet/mvc/condition/ProducesRequestCondition$ProduceMediaTypeExpression' }
    stack: { 'org/springframework/http/MediaType', 'org/springframework/http/MediaType' }
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 0336 051c 1504 9f00 0c15 041c 6436 05a7
    0000010: 0049 1c02 9f00 442b b700 3b1c b900 3d02
    0000020: 00c0 0006 3a06 2db7 003b 1504 b900 3d02
    0000030: 00c0 0006 3a07 1906 1907 b600 4136 0515
    0000040: 0599 0008 1505 a700 1019 06b6 0026 1907
    0000050: b600 26b6 0042 3605 1505 ac            
  Stackmap Table:
    append_frame(@18,Integer)
    append_frame(@73,Object[#178],Object[#178])
    same_locals_1_stack_item_frame(@86,Integer)
    chop_frame(@88,2)

    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.createRequestMappingInfo(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:242)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getMappingForMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:191)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.getMappingForMethod(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:51)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping$1.matches(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:152)
    at org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethodSelector$1.doWith(HandlerMethodSelector.java:62)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:480)
    at org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethodSelector.selectMethods(HandlerMethodSelector.java:58)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.detectHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.initHandlerMethods(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:124)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractHandlerMethodMapping.java:103)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerMapping.afterPropertiesSet(RequestMappingHandlerMapping.java:126)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 21 more
```

spring issues are hidden from my understanding, what could it be, where to start for a search?

Comment: I would say check your dependencies/classpath. I would expect a conflicting jar (different version) somewhere.

Comment: Had the same problem. Using spring 4.0.5. Any news or update on this?

Comment: After deleting the deployment descriptor and restarting the server starts to work again. Reproducible for spring 4.0.2 for tomee app server 1.7.1 in NetBeans 8.0.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, It is not an upgrading issue. It is occur when your application server stuck. So, you needs to delete the server and run on server.

Comment: that's is pretty close as it happens: after deleting the deployment descriptor and restarting it works again.

Comment: I encountered the same problem in other system (not Spring) but I can not fix it. The problem is: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52397656/the-exception-java-lang-verifyerror-bad-type-on-operand-stack-happend-in-heron/52397748?noredirect=1#comment91740126_52397748). Any suggestions is helpful.